# Flutter how to get an item of class

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and I want to know how to get a particular item of a class User.

**This is my class User:**

```
class UsersList{
  List<User> users;

  UsersList({
    this.users
  });

  factory UsersList.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
    List<User> users= List<User>();

    users= json.map((i) => User.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return UsersList(
      users : users
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "users": users,
  };

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{'
        'users: ${this.users},'
        '}';
  }
}

class User{
  int type;
  String name;
  bool gender;

  User({
    this.type,
    this.name,
    this.gender,
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return User(
      type : json['type'],
      name: json['name'],
      gender : json['gender'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "type" : type,
    "name" : name,
    "gender" : gender,
  };

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{'
        'type : ${this.type},'
        'name: ${this.name},'
        'gender : ${this.gender},'
        '}';
  }
 }
```

**I want to get a particular User, this is my function :**
I have a key parameter in my function to be able to search according to the values ​​that I want (example: name, gender, ...) but I do not see how to use this parameter in my class because it does not recognize key?

```
static User getUser(var value, String key, UsersList items)
  {
    print(items.users.where((c) => (c.key == value)).toList().first);
  }
```

Is this the good method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to access user with key, in order to do that you can make use of toJson() method, example is

```
static User getUser(var value, String key, UsersList items){
    return users.where((c) => (c.toJson()['name'] == 'name')).toList().first;
}
```

In User object you have mentioned gender as bool and this practice will confuse, use can name it as isMale/isFemale, then it won't be confused later for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a low number of keys, it's going to be much more performant to manually do the mapping in code:

```
static User getUser(var value, String key, UsersList items) {
  bool Function(User) matchingFn;

  if (key == 'name') {
    matchingFn = (c) => c.name == value;
  } else if (key == 'type') {
    matchingFn = (c) => c.type == value;
  } else if (key == 'gender') {
    matchingFn = (c) => c.gender == value;
  }

  return items.users.firstWhere(matchingFn);
}
```

The `.firstWhere(fn)` is also much better than `.where(fn).toList().first`;

Comment: I have a lot more parameters I simplified for the example but I note for the firstWhere thank you

Comment: As soon as you have a relatively high number of users, converting to JSON every time you want to do comparison is going to be prohibitive. JSON is a serialization tool, not a search tool :D

Comment: If you have lots of data and attributes on each, it'd better for you to use a proper database, like Hive or Moor. Each of those have very nice API and documentation on how to use them efficiently.

Comment: I don't want to use a database because my project must be able to be used without internet, I keep my application data in json files stored on the application